# How to send file access url for a file stored in google drive to client in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I am using google drive to store documents submitted to my laravel api.I have created a service provider for google drive with the following boot function:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        //
        \Storage::extend("google", function($app, $config){
            $client = new \Google_Client;
            $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
            $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
            $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
            $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);
            return new Filesystem($adapter);
        });
    }
```

I have also performed all the other necessary steps like adding 'google' disk inside `filesystems.php` which includes all the necessary values like 'driver', 'clientId' etc.

I can successfully save incoming documents to google drive by simply calling store with "google" as second argument as bellows:

```
$request->file('document')->store("", "google");
```

But it seems this returns only the name of the file stored in the drive. But as a response I want to send a link which can be used to redirect the user to view the particular document in the drive. How may I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) on the file id that is returned.

```
$service->files->GetFiles($fileId);
```

Assuming that its a google drive type file then there should be a link which would allow the user to open the file in google drive. [file response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)

However you should note that unless you set the permissions on the file to public the users not going to have access to the file as it is owned by the service account.

Comment: @DalmTo I am very new to laravel and php in general so it may be a dumb question to ask. What do I assign service variable in the code you gave suggested?

Comment: @DalmTo It must be inside the boot function. If so how do I pass the file id to that function and insure that the access link is returned when calling the store function?